# can't load image that save in media in url

Tags: django, django-settings

I search many place but I can't find a solution for my problem.here is my `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

in `modesl.py` I have a imagefield:

```
class comp(modesl.Model):
    picture = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads_image/", blank=True)
```

and image save in media folder in correct place :

```
>>> user= User.objects.get(firstName = "dsf")
>>> post = user.competence_set.all()[0]
>>> post.picture
<FieldFile: social/media/picture/asdasd_29_2013-11-28 22:08:06.909316.png>
```

I have two app `social` and `ajax` that in `social` I have `static` folder and `media` folder when I type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/social/images/logos/pylogo.png` my image loads but when I type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/pictures/test.png` I got 404 not found django page I want to load image in template that save in Db but this doesn't work. where I am wrong? (also when I type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/social/media/picture/asdasd_29_2013-11-28%2022:08:06.909316.png` get not found 404 error )

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: in my home `1.5.1` and in my server `1.4`

Answer (score 0):

For user-uploaded images to work you need to set:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/' # or wherever your uploaded media files are
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: this means that in same place that `static` folder is saved I have another folder that name is `media` and in this have a another `media` folder ? right ?

Comment: @mojibuntu you can organise it on your hard disk as you wish but both `MEDIA_` settings need to be configured.

Comment: I mean what is the hierarchy of media folder in my project should be ? is `media` folder is beside my apps or inside my apps (beside `static` folder)

Comment: @mojibuntu besides the apps and beside the `static` directory as it's only the directory into which you upload.

Comment: I am using django 1.5 and in 1.5 apps is not at same place as static folder

Comment: @mojibuntu then I'm not sure. Either way the same principles hold: you need to specify a directory where the user-uploaded files go and you need to specify a URL by which the media files can be accessed.